# Accessing Container view controller from parent controller in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

I want to access label of container view controller from parent view controller. I have tried the following:

prepareForSegue is a function in parent view controller.
ViewController2 is the container view controller. 
parin2 is the name of the label in the container view controller.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!)
{
    let vc1 = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2;
    vc1.parin2.text=String("helo");
}
```

This gives the following error:

```
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't say exactly *which* line caused the error, but my guess is that it was `let vc1 = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2` (by the way, please omit the ';'s in Swift). The `as!` appears to be failing because the destination view controller isn't a `ViewController2`. To verify this, set a breakpoint on that line, then examine the segue's `destinationViewController` property to see what kind of view controller it is. If it's *not* a `ViewController2`, then the problem is in your storyboard. Either you're getting a segue that you didn't expect, or the class of the destination in the storyboard isn't a `ViewController2`.

A better pattern for handling `prepareForSegue` is the following:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    // ALWAYS check the segue identifier first! If you forgot to put one on
    // your segue in the storyboard, then you should see a compiler warning.
    switch segue.identifier {
    case "SegueToViewController2":
        guard let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController2 else {
            // handle the error somehow
            return
        }
    default:
        // What happens when the segue's identifier doesn't match any of the
        // ones that you expected?
    }
}
```